# pgfplots - center ybars in the middle of the chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using pgfplots for the first time and trying to generate bar charts for a paper. This is the source code that I have, but I want to center the two sets of the bars in the middle of the chart. Any ideas how this can be done?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1,},
    ylabel={Negative Log Likelihood},
    symbolic x coords={Dataset 1,Dataset 2},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={ align=center},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,400) (Dataset 2,751)};
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,391) (Dataset 2,751)};
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,270) (Dataset 2,720)};
\legend{Algo 1,Algo 2,Algo 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlarge x limits=1,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1,},
    ylabel={Negative Log Likelihood},
    symbolic x coords={Dataset 1,Dataset 2},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={ align=center},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,400) (Dataset 2,751)};
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,391) (Dataset 2,751)};
\addplot coordinates {(Dataset 1,270) (Dataset 2,720)};
\legend{Algo 1,Algo 2,Algo 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The important part here to achieve the result is `enlarge x limits=1`.